# Angular ID autoincremental in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I´m working on a user CRUD with Angular. I can delete, read and update all users but when I want save i have one problem: The users have a increment ID.

I use 'file inputs' to add new email and user, but I want add increment ID.

I have this code, but can´t add 'newID' in push $scope.

```
$scope.users = [];
$scope.newUsers = [];

$scope.addUser = function() {
    var newId = $scope.users.length + 1;
    $scope.users.push($scope.newUsers);
};
```

In HTML

```
<form ng-submit="addUser()">     
    <input type="text" ng-model="newUsers.name" required>
    <input  type="email" ng-model="newUsers.email" required>
    <button>Agregar</button>
</form>
```

Comment: What is the code to your ng-submit `user` function?

Comment: I would handle that in Sql by using an INT IDENTITY field. That way you don't have to bother setting the Id as it will always be the user length + 1.

Comment: user function not exist, copy-paste error, sorry. Ng-submit have addUser name. This test don´t have SQL, I trying to do pure angularjs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the property on the `newUsers`

```
$scope.addUser = function() {
   $scope.newUsers.ID = $scope.users.length + 1;
    $scope.users.push($scope.newUsers);
};
```

Also, `newUsers` should be an **object**(with {}) not an **array**(with [])

`$scope.newUsers = {};`

Comment: With this change console.log($scope.users.newUsers); Return undefined.

Comment: `console.log($scope.users);` this is the correct way

Comment: Adding $scope.newUsers.id = $scope.users.length + 1;                         and $scope.users.push($scope.newUsers); can add only more user. If i need to add more, the last values overwrite. It´s a partial solution, but i want to need multiples users :$.  FIXED: Finally i need to add $scope.newUsers = {}; to clean input fields and can add more than one user. Thank M B.